# Draw Connection line between two forms outside Form bounds C#

Tags: c#, forms, graphics

I am trying to draw a line between two forms for my specific use. I want to know how to draw a Connection line between two forms outside the form bounds. I tried using the GetDC and tried to draw it on desktop but its deleted when something moves in that area or when refreshed. I dont have any events to redraw again. I tried using a back form making it transparent and draw in it but it is very slow and i am unable to click anything thats backside of the form. I have seen a sample in visual studio. I want to draw a line like the below one.

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=B140DB4D2C1B55DB!111&authkey=!APebmlRlneUpSn4&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use windows API can fulfill drawing line between windows. We need add event handler for the both windows' resizing, then invoke Windows API such as *lineTo* to draw a line on desktop.

I'm a beginner of Windows API and need research further more to apply the full solution. So just show the line drawing method. While I'm sure it can work.

```
    #include <windows.h>

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
               HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
               LPSTR lpCmdLine,
               int nShowCmd)
{
HDC         hdc;
HWND        hwnd;
COLORREF    clr;

hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
//DC of desktop
hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);

//Background color
SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);

MoveToEx  (hdc, 0, 0, NULL) ;

//The line will disappear after refreshing
LineTo    (hdc, 500, 500) ; 
ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

Sleep(5000);    

return 0;
```

}

Comment: I'm looking into adding message loop handler to keep the line after refreshing.

Comment: But this will be deleted on refresh of the screen right? I want the line to be exactly same like in visual studio.